# Getting a deployed MVC page in IIS 7.5. to run a batch file from the command line

Tags: .net, command-line, batch-file, iis-7.5, web-deployment

For one of my projects I needed to integrate a .NET page with an outside call to a MATLAB process. In order to do this (and not spend any money in doing so), I created a batch file to be called by the .NET page itself (ASP.NET MVC 3, if that matters any) which basically contains one line--that to start up MATLAB and run this process.

The end of the process itself spits out information into a text file and then shuts down MATLAB. When the .NET page sees that the file has been created it grabs it and spits out some calculations based on the data found in that file. This process has been working perfectly on my local machine, and when I run it from VS 2012 (in debug mode) on the server.

The fun part comes with deploying this site. I have successfully deployed my site to the internet, and everything on it works well, *except* for this process. It appears to not be running at all. The directory that contains this batch file has all the necessary permissions attached to it (IUSR and IIS_IUSRS), and yet seems to not be running at all.

Can anybody please tell me how to get this batch file to run properly in a web page being hosted on IIS 7.5? And yes, I do know that this is not the best of ideas security-wise, but I just need to get this done.

EDIT: Here's the code for calling the process:

```
var matlabProcess = new Process {
    StartInfo = {
        FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2012a\\bin\\WebCall.bat", 
        Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", seeds, weights)
    }
};

matlabProcess.Start();
```

The batch file contains the following:

```
cd\
cd progra~1\MATLAB\r2012a\bin
start matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -r WebCall(%1,%2)
```

EDIT: A friend of mine suggested that the reason that this is failing is because there's no handler on IIS for a batch file, and therefore IIS has no idea how to even run that file. If so, can someone then please tell me how to create a proper handler mapping so that I can see if his solution was correct?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. there are no error messages? 2. The number 1 thing I see in deployment problems is that PATHs are not set the same, else, you can change your .bat file to use a full /path/to/matlab. Just some ideas, sorry if they're too obvious. Good luck and HYN!

Comment: 1) No error messages.  2) Now posting the code for calling the process.

Comment: To rule out or in a permissions problem I would *temporarily* run the application pool with the account with the highest permissions possible (administrator) to see if that 'fixes' your problem.
Also you need to start your process and log the standard error/output to see whats going on there.

Comment: yes, but what's inside the `. bat` file? Good luck!

Comment: This solution will not scale.

Comment: Can you monitor the server via Task Manager and see if matlab starts up?

Comment: Good to see you again @Dan-o! Hope your application is coming along. I realize that this won't scale, but it doesn't have to (if it gets more than 5 hits a day I will be pleasantly surprised). MATLAB does not start up at all, even on Task Manager.

Comment: When you say deployed to Internet. What do you mean?  Your own server? Hosted server?

Comment: My own server. The university I'm getting my Masters from set up a Windows 7 machine that I converted into an IIS 7.5 web server to host this site.

Comment: If this isn't working still, ... one more thing to try, would be to add something like `c:` or `cd c:\progra~1\MATLAB\r2012a\bin`. Recall that DOS based commands require a separate navagation cmd to change from 1 drive letter to another. The only thing I can think of to add to your `.bat` file to "debug" that case is to add a `dir` before and after your `cd ...` cmd, just to confirm you're functioning on the drive that you want to use. Good luck.

Comment: IIS is not interacting with the batch file in this instance. Process.Start calls the Win32 API function CreateProcess(...).

Comment: I've deleted my answer so that people know this question still needs attention.

Comment: What does the Event Viewer say?  Any errors logged there?  The IIS error logs?

Comment: No errors are logged in the Event Viewer. Where can I find the IIS error logs?

Answer (score 0):

64 Bit OS?  If so, perhaps you have some redirection going on.  If it is a 32 bit app, you should be specifying %ProgramFiles(x86)%.  It's best to check and use the appropriate one so it works on either 32 or 64 bit.

Are you executing from a UNC location (requires considerations on some newer OS's and may not be possible on Win 8 and 2012 Server)?

Put this as the first statement in the bat file:

```
echo.CD=%cd% & pause
```